# Get value from string in JavaScript efficiently

Tags: javascript

How could I get a variable/property from a string in JavaScript?

The string `obj.val` returns the value of `obj.val`. Is adding `\"` to the beginning and end of the string enough?
Thanks! :)

Unlike the post some of you have suggested, the values I want don't have string keys.

Comment: Can you explain more why you would want to do this?

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key) and there also is a [lodash function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) for it

Comment: It's not a string key though

Answer (score 0):

you can get value of `variable` with `string` name with `this[yourString]` or with `scope[yourString]`.

```
var someVar = "Hello world!";
this["someVar"] //this print value of variable name "someVar"

var obj = {}; obj.var = "some object!";
this["obj"]["var"] //this will get value of object property with "var"
```

Comment: I mean without a string name. Like `var test = [5, 2];
var x = "test[0]";`. How would I get the value `5` from `x`?